# Unresponsive elasticsearch under docker compose on mac m1

Tags: docker, macos, elasticsearch, apple-m1

I am using Mac M1 Ventura with docker version 23.0.5.
I am trying to run elasticsearch locally using official elasticsearch document https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/docker.html
but my container is non responsive.

The command to start the container.

```
docker run --name elasticsearch \
    --net elastic \
    -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 \
    -e "discovery.type=single-node" \
    -e "bootstrap.memory_lock=false" \
    -e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g" \
    -t docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.6.2
```

I have already created elastic network.

The container logs, process has started but doesn't respond to cluster health endpoint.

```
curl http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health
```

Always get empty response from the servers.

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

This happens even when I try to run the the command from inside the container.

I don't see any logs in elasticsearch docker process of receiving this request.

I ran Netcat and servers is listening.

```
 nc -z localhost 9200              
Connection to localhost port 9200 [tcp/wap-wsp] succeeded!
```

I have tried different options.

Running as docker compose process following https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk.
Bumping docker desktop CPU and memory settings.
Disabling xpack.security option.

Nothing has yielded any different results.
I can see elasticsearch process running and high CPU and memory utilization. But nothing is logs.

Does anyone know any possible issues or how I can debug it further?

Edit:

This is my local docker compose setup.

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${ELK_VERSION}
    environment:
    - bootstrap.memory_lock=false
    - bootstrap.system_call_filter=false
    - cluster.name=docker-cluster
    - cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled=false
    - discovery.type=single-node
    - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g
    ulimits:
     memlock:
      hard: -1
      soft: -1
    volumes:
    - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro,Z
    - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:Z
    ports:
    - 9200:9200
    - 9300:9300
    networks:
    - elastic
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "2.0"
          memory: "2g"
      
volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

The content of elasticsearch file is as follows:

```
---
## Default Elasticsearch configuration from Elasticsearch base image.
## https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/main/distribution/docker/src/docker/config/elasticsearch.yml
#
cluster.name: docker-cluster
network.host: 0.0.0.0

## X-Pack settings
## see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-settings.html
#
xpack.license.self_generated.type: trial
xpack.security.enabled: false
```

Edit 2:

I tried to run safe experiment on `CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009` with `Docker version 23.0.6, build ef23cbc`.

Its able to start elasticsearch cluster and I am also getting logs telling why my request failed

```
"@timestamp":"2023-05-08T19:21:04.027Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/172.18.0.2:9200, remoteAddress=/172.18.0.1:49690}", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[6203e5a2f04e][transport_worker][T#4]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"CQaFO9TwR1atM_76xOAGfw","elasticsearch.node.id":"t8MTpKfyQUenWQSlhPjduA","elasticsearch.node.name":"6203e5a2f04e","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}
```

That's not the case with Apple M1.

Edit 3:
I am able to successful response to curl call for `_cluster/health` endpoint in Centos7 VM.

The command I ran is as follows

```
docker run --name elasticsearch --net elastic -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" -t docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.6.2
```

disabled the xpack security feature.

```
curl http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health
{"cluster_name":"docker-cluster","status":"green","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary_shards":1,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":0,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":100.0}
```

So I think its issue with M1 chip.

Comment: Try `curl https://...` i.e. with SSL as ES 8.x runs with security enabled by default. See points 3-4-5 of the lin you posted

Comment: By default, elasticsearch binds to the loopback address, which will be container local. The guide you linked configures `elasticsearch.yml` to have `network.host: _non_loopback_`, What are the values of your elasticsearch.yml files?

Comment: @Val, I have disabled security feature. That means ssl is not required, right?

Comment: @IanGabes, I have setup network.host to 0.0.0.0 so that it can be accessed from the host machine.

Comment: @pragmaticEngineer ok fair enough then, that wasn't in the problem statement

Answer (score 1):

I found out the workaround.
If I used `docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.6.2-amd64` instead of `docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.6.2`. I get it to work on my Apple M1 machine.

Its referenced in https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/known-issues/
certain docker images need to run under emulator.

Comment: So what do you think is the cause of the problem?